# Cannot remove an image inserted with MediaStore

Tags: android, image, mediastore

I'm saving an image loaded with Picasso to be shared afterwards. This is the code I'm using to save it:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(), mImageBitmap, "Shared image", null);

return Uri.parse(path);
```

Now, when the image has been shared, I have to delete it using the URI. I've tried some answers I've seen here but none of them has worked. The image still appears in the gallery. These are the methods I have used:

---

```
// Set up the projection (we only need the ID)
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };

// Match on the file path
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { new File(mImageUri.toString()).getAbsolutePath() };

// Query for the ID of the media matching the file path
Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(queryUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) 
{
    // We found the ID. Deleting the item via the content provider will also remove the file
    long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
    Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
}

c.close();
```

---

```
File file = new File(mImageUri.toString());
// This returns false
file.delete();

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(mImageUri.toString()))));
```

Any idea of what i've done wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know the image has been shared successfully? Using startActivityForResult? But then how do we confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Try this for deletion

```
    String[] retCol = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                retCol,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE + "='"+TEMP_FILE_TITLE+"'", null, null
        );
    try {
        if (cur.getCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id
        );
       int cnt = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}finally {
                cur.close();
            }
```

In your case replace TEMP_FILE_TITLE = "Shared image"