# Android Delete image file using uri created by Media Insert Image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, uri, delete-file

I am Using below function to get Uri from Bitmap :

```
Uri GetImjUriFrmBitmapFnc(Bitmap SrcBitmapPsgVal)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream BytAryOptVaj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SrcBitmapPsgVal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, BytAryOptVaj);

    String ImjPthVar = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), SrcBitmapPsgVal, "TmpTtl", null);
    Uri ImjBitmapUriVar = Uri.parse(ImjPthVar);
    return ImjBitmapUriVar;
}
```

I am Using below function to get Bitmap back from Uri :

```
Bitmap GetImjBitmapFrmImjUriFnc(Uri ImjUriPsgVaj, boolean WanDelImjPsgVab)
{
    Bitmap OptImjBitmapVar;
    try
    {
        OptImjBitmapVar = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), ImjUriPsgVaj);
        if(WanDelImjPsgVab) FylDelImjUsgUriFnc(ImjUriPsgVaj);
    }
    catch (IOException ErrVar)
    {
        ErrVar.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return OptImjBitmapVar;
}

void FylDelImjUsgUriFnc(Uri FylUriPsgVal)
{
    getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + "=?",
            new String[]{FylUriPsgVal.getPath()});
}

boolean FylDelFnc(Uri FylUriPsgVal)
{
    File DelFylVaj = new File(FylUriPsgVal.getPath());
    if (DelFylVaj.exists()) return DelFylVaj.delete();
    else return false;
}
```

I tried to delete the created Uri using both the method

```
FylDelImjUsgUriFnc(Uri FylUriPsgVal) <br>
FylDelFnc(Uri FylUriPsgVal)
```

But Its not working...

Kindly let me know how can I delete the created Uri...

|*| Please ignore the diff std of function and variables names I am using....

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828023/cannot-remove-an-image-inserted-with-mediastore/47361402#47361402 might be help to you.